# How Rails app can find out which OS it's running on

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some of development is done on Linux, some on Windows. 
Depending on which OS the app is currently running on, it needs to load different config files.

Is there any "Rails way" to do so?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Ruby constant `RUBY_PLATFORM`

The only gotcha is on JRuby, which lists `"java"` as the RUBY_PLATFORM, no matter which OS it is. On windows there is win32, mingw32 or cygwin.

Another solution is to use the [sys_uname](http://rubyforge.org/docman/view.php/610/1561/sys_uname.html) package from the [sysutils](http://rubyforge.org/projects/sysutils) gem, if the method above doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Just found out how to get platform from JRuby: org.jruby.platform.Platform::OS or helpers like: org.jruby.platform.Platform::IS_WINDOWS.  http://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/src/org/jruby/platform/Platform.java